422 Unprocessable Entity error when sending Form data to FastAPI backend using ReactJs and Fetch API in the frontend
I keep getting the 422 Unprocessable Entity error with the follwoing missing fields:
{"detail":[{"type":"missing","loc":["body","username"],"msg":"Field required","input":null},{"type":"missing","loc":["body","password"],"msg":"Field required","input":null}]}

I tried everything possible, but the error persists.
This is my frontend code:
const Login = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleLogin = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    const formData = new URLSearchParams();
    formData.append('username', email); // Assuming the backend expects 'username'
    formData.append('password', password);

    try {
      const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/token', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData,
      });

      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('Login failed');
      }

and this is the backend:
@fastapi_router.post("/token", response_model=Token)
async def login_for_access_token(
    username: Annotated[str, Form()],
    password: Annotated[str, Form()],
    db: AsyncSession = Depends(database.get_db)
):
    user = await auth.authenticate_user(db, username, password)
    if not user:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
            detail="Incorrect username or password",
            headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"},
        )
    access_token_expires = timedelta(minutes=envs.access_token_expire_minutes)
    access_token = auth.create_access_token(
        data={"sub": user.username}, expires_delta=access_token_expires
    )
    logger.info(f"Access Token: {access_token}")
    return {"access_token": access_token, "token_type": "bearer"}

Any help would be appreciated.

Does this answer your question (please have a look at Option 2)?

This answer might prove helpful as well.

Hey @Chris, thanks for responses. I tried everything, even with FormData on js side, i tried annotated vs non-annotated function parameters for the backend: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-forms/#__tabbed_1_3
I tried different headers and content-types. Its not working with any approach, im lowkey fuming.

Here is a working example on how to submit Form data to a FastAPI backend using JavaScript Fetch API in the frontend. Related answers where you can read more on the methods used below could be found here, as well as here and here.
Note that when expecting username and password fields as form data, one could alternatively use the OAuth2PasswordRequestForm dependency class offered by FastAPI. Related answers on that class can be seen here, as well as here, here and here.
Working Example
app.py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Form, Request
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse

app = FastAPI()
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")


@app.post("/submit")
async def submit(username: str = Form(...), password: str = Form(...)):
    return {"username": username, "password": password}


@app.get("/", response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def main(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {"request": request})

templates/index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
      <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="send()">
      <p id="resp"></p>
      <script>
         function send() {
            var resp = document.getElementById("resp");
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("username", "test");
            formData.append("password", "pass");
         
            fetch('/submit', {
                  method: 'POST',
                  body: formData,
               })
               .then(response => response.json())
               .then(data => {
                  resp.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data); // data is a JSON object
               })
               .catch(error => {
                  console.error(error);
               });
         }
      </script>
   </body>
</html>


This test template helped me debug and find the root cause of my issue. I was using custom fastapi middleware for logging the incoming request, and for some reason, it worked when I removed this middleware. I assume it was changing the content type of the request data

This may also happen if you are using Axios in reactjs and in the axiosConfig.js file you accidentally set a specific header content type which is used for any request when you are importing the axiosInstance initialized in axiosConfig.js. This may go un-noticed
